# Google Cloud: How to move kubernetes cluster to different region?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a kubernetes cluster that is currently running in the region europe-north1 and zone europe-north1-a.
I want to move this cluster to the new region europe-west3 with the zone europe-west3-b to get access to nvidia-tesla-t4 accelerators.

```
gcloud compute accelerator-types list
NAME                   ZONE                       DESCRIPTION
nvidia-tesla-t4        europe-west3-b             NVIDIA Tesla T4
```

I tried to update the cluster via the gcloud CLI but the standard update command seems not to support this kind of operation.

**Error: "Specified location "europe-west3-b" is not a valid zone in the cluster\'s region "europe-north1"."**

```
gcloud container clusters update cluster-1 \
      --region europe-north1 \
      --node-locations europe-west3-b
Updating cluster-1...
30 .........................done.
31 ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.update) Operation [<Operation
32  clusterConditions: [<StatusCondition
33  message: u'Specified location "europe-west3-b" is not a valid zone in the cluster\'s region "europe-north1".'>]
```

Is there any efficient way to move cluster between regions?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones  explains how to move to diferent zone, but sheds light on moving to another region as well. I'll be trying to move my test GKE cluster to another region tomorrow. Please let me know if you have already managed to move your cluster to another region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can’t move things between regions at all, least of all an entire running cluster. You’ll need to back up your data and restore it onto a new cluster in the new region.

Comment: Maybe Anthos is able to do this. No yet tested, too expensive for now